# How add a trailing slash after the port in apache URIBuilder?

Tags: java, uribuilder

I am trying to build a URI having a trailing slash but can't happen to find the way to do it with URIBuilder. Is that even possible?

Expected result would be:  `http://test.com:24/?param1=value1&param2=value2`

```
@Test
public void ttt(){
    final URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder();
    uriBuilder.setScheme("http");
    uriBuilder.setHost("test.com");
    uriBuilder.setPort(24);
    uriBuilder.addParameter("param1", "value1");
    uriBuilder.addParameter("param2", "value2");
    System.out.println(uriBuilder.toString());
}
```

What I get at the moment: `http://test.com:24?param1=value1&param2=value2`

Any idea?

Comment: what purpose is the slash supposed to have? There should be no difference on the server handling both requests.

Comment: I am trying to rebuild an existing function and, comparing the results, that's the only difference I can spot. I imagine that some other services might filter that syntax so I m trying to reproduce

Comment: It would be useful to say which URIBuilder you are using. With Google I only found two versions of UriBuilder (different letter case) and URI.builder() but not URIBuilder. I only learnt which one it was by looking at an answer.

Comment: I mentioned it in the title: "apache URIBuilder"  but that's a good point, I should have linked the documentation to avoid confusion [link](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-5.0.x/current/httpcore5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/core5/net/URIBuilder.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `setPath(str)` method, see [URIBuilder.setPath(String)](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-5.0.x/current/httpcore5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/core5/net/URIBuilder.html#setPath(java.lang.String))

So your code should look like

```
@Test
public void ttt(){
    final URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder();
    uriBuilder.setScheme("http");
    uriBuilder.setHost("test.com");
    uriBuilder.setPort(24);
    uriBuilder.setPath("/");
    uriBuilder.addParameter("param1", "value1");
    uriBuilder.addParameter("param2", "value2");
    System.out.println(uriBuilder.toString());
}
```

Output

```
http://test.com:24/?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always add manually the slash:

```
int len = "http://test.com:24".length()
String newstr = uriBuilder.toString().substring(0,len) + "/" + uriBuilder.toString().substring(len);
System.out.println(newstr)
```

Since you know the url (you have built it manually) you can use this way to add the slash.
More general solution is to find the second ':' and add slash after the last digit of the port:

```java
String str = uriBuilder.toString();
int ind = str.indexOf(':',6) + 1;
while(ind < str.length() && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(ind)))
    ind++;
String newstr = str.substring(0,ind) + "/" + str.substring(ind);
```

Comment: I think that converting the URIBuilder into String would defeat the purpose of trying to secure the URI. Also, I simplified the code here but the scheme, port, host and parameters are all provided variables.